# Excel Countifs multiple coumns

Tags: excel

I have an audit spreadsheet that lists multiple columns, with a descriptive criteria, action date, and result date and need to count the number of times the result occurred after the action date. These dates both vary for each line. I have tried the following formula with no result:

```
=COUNTIFS($G$2:$G$300,"R*",$E$2:$E$300,"<="&$H$2:$H$300)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get the number of times cells in col H is greater than cells in col E and Cells in Col G start with a R, the below formula should work

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(H2:H7>E2:E7)*(LEFT(G2:G7,1)="R"))
```

Comment: Thank you it does. I clearly need to dig a little deeper for my programming.